# Webpack: wrong absolute path in compiled CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, web, webpack

I'm migrating an Angular 1 project in order to be able to deploy everything with Webpack.
So far, I managed to configure almost everything but I'm having issues trying to export the static assets (fonts and images mostly).

I've configured the ExtractTextPlugin as below

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader','css-loader', {allChunks: true}) }
```

and in the compiled CSS the paths are replaced but the resulting absolute path is wrong. In fact the resulting path is `/assetsweb/assets/..` while I expect it to be `/assets/..`.

I cannot understand where the `/assetsweb` part is coming from.

Here's the Webpack configuration I'm using

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry:{
        web: "./web/wayonara.js",
        mobile: "./mobile/wayonara.js"
    },
    output:{
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "/[name]/bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets"
    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ENV: JSON.stringify('dev')
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            EXIF: "exif-js",
            "window.EXIF":"exif-js"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("/[name]/assets/css/bundle.css")
    ],
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /bower_components/],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader','css-loader', {allChunks: true}) },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance,

Best,

Maurizio

Comment: Can you show your complete webpack config?

Comment: @Neal, sure. Here it's, I edited the question